# Setting a fake extension method for UserManager using MicrosoftFakes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to write some unit tests for my ASP.NET MVC project to test my controller which works with UserManager and uses its extension method FindById(string). I generated fakes for the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity where the method is stored so I got ShimUserManagerExtensions but I was not able to actually assign a new behaviour because I have zero idea how to do it and I wasn't able to find it anywhere.

Here's what I get when I'm trying to access the method.

[image: Picture]

I've tried to assign something to it as follows

```
ShimUserManagerExtensions.FindByIdOf2UserManagerOfM0M1M1 = () => new ApplicationUser();
```

But I was told that FindByIdOf2UserManagerOfM0M1M1 is a method group and I can't assign anything to it. As I understand, that means there are some overloaded methods and I have to assign my behaviour to the exact one. However, I don't know how to do it.

Could someone please give me a hint or perhaps just tell how to formulate the query for google so I'll find any information?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

```
ShimUserManagerExtensions
            .FindByIdOf2UserManagerOfM0M1M1<ApplicationUser, string>(
                (m, u) => new ApplicationUser());
```